# Connecting a supply voltage from linear encoder to camera IO board with a current limiter

Tags: resistors, current-limiting, camera, encoder

I have a TTL output from an incremental linear encoder which also supplies a 5V output at 140 mA. I would like to use this 5V output voltage to power a camera IO board with RS422 Interface which has a specification of 5V/50mA.

How do I reduce the current from 140mA to 50mA. Can I just use a 150 Ohm resistor or have you got any suggestions ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f86TCO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please find the camera IO board specifications below :
Pin......Level.............Description..........Default
1........RS422.............GPIO_P0(input).......Incremental encoder(high)
2........RS422.............GPIO_P1(input).......Lightbarrier(high)
3........LVCMOS............GPIO_P4..............Can be used for lightbarriers
4........LVCMOS............GPIO_P2..............Reserved
5........3.3Vover100Ohm....Power................Output
6........LVCMOS............GPIO_P3..............Master/Slave-interface
7........0V................Ground...............-
8........LVCMOS............GPIO_N4..............Master/Slave-interface
9........RS422.............GPIO_N0(input).......Incremental encoder(low)
10.......RS422.............GPIO_N1(input).......Lightbarrier(low)
11.......0V................Ground...............-
12.......LVCMOS............GPIO_N2..............Reserved
13.......0V................Ground...............-
14.......LVCMOS............GPIO_N3..............Reserved
15.......5Vover100Ohm......Powersupply..........Output

Comment: I should have mentioned more clearly. There is a digital IO Interface Card within a camera and it is specified to use a external 5V power supply with a series 100 Ohm resistor . As the complete IO interface including power supply and the canal inputs are packed into 15 Pin D-Sub Connector, I would like to send the signals directly from the encoder itself. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the camera needs 5 volts and takes up to 50 mA then supply it with 5 volts and even if the supply is *capable* of proviging 140 mA (or more) it doesn't matter because the camera will take only the current it needs to operate. I expect that the 140 mA figure is a maximum rating for the device i.e. it is capable of supplying 5 volts to a load than can take up to 140 mA.

Regards your comment, this contradicts what your main question body appears to say so please provide a link to the camera interface card data sheet so this contradiction can be resolved.

Comment: That is correct, 140mA is the maximum rating for the device. Please find the link in the question.The extra comment was made in reply to a person who had answered, but made a decision to revert back his answers.

Comment: I don't have an account with whoever that link was for the data sheet.

Comment: I have added the IO Board specs in my question

Comment: I would need to see a full data sheet to resolve this.

Comment: Datasheet is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13GqfIl0xE4INbg5tYcueuR5eNlT-Bh0I/view?usp=sharing) and the Digital IO Port configuration is in page 38

Comment: That page specifies a 5 volt output and not a power in connection. In other words it is used for powering an external circuit that takes a light load. The camera power is 24 volts as shown on page 36.